# Extending Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Freeshipping causes odd behavior

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, free-shipping

1. When the module is enabled, refreshing the cart page will sometimes return `Fatal error: Call to a member function setStore() on a non-object in /var/www/html/site-magento19/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Shipping.php on line 424`
2. Though it seems to be trying to rewrite the class (guessing by the error above) I cannot get any results.

## Most Recent: Module/Enhancedshipping/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Module_Enhancedshipping>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </Module_Enhancedshipping>
    </modules>
    <global>
         <models>
           <shipping>
             <rewrite>
                  <carrier_freeshipping>Module_Enhancedshipping_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Freeshipping</carrier_freeshipping>
             </rewrite>
           </shipping>
         </models>
    </global> 
</config>
```

## Module/Enhancedshipping/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Freeshipping.php

```
<?php

class Module_Enhancedshipping_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Freeshipping extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Freeshipping {
   public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        die('Because I want results'); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<enhancedshipping>` should be `<shipping>`. Try below config.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Module_Enhancedshipping>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </Module_Enhancedshipping>
    </modules>
    <global>
         <models>
           <shipping>
             <rewrite>
                  <carrier_freeshipping>Module_Enhancedshipping_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Freeshipping</carrier_freeshipping>
             </rewrite>
           </shipping>
         </models>
    </global> 
</config>
```

Also it's good practice to use full php tag, `<?php`. short tags can lead to errors if it's not enabled in php.ini

Comment: I've implemented the changes that you recommended (updated in original post). However, my model is still not being called. Would observing the model instead help me in case another module rewrites the same class? That said this is a fresh install of magento with zero customizations other than the one I am attempting to implement.

Comment: the `fatal error` you are getting is because magento is not able to find your new shipping carrier class. Please make sure full tags (`<?php`), file path and class name are correct.

Comment: Everything is exactly as it appears above. I've updated my PHP tags as well.

Comment: looks perfectly fine to me.. I believe you cleared the cache to check it again right?

Comment: Have you changed `<module>` to `<modules>` tag in config.xml file? in the original question it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

As you have want to rewrite the class `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Freeshipping` then  should be change the `<shipping>`.

If we accumulate `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Freeshipping` class  in factory  pattern then it should be  `'shipping/carrier_freeshipping'`

`shipping` call as `model prefix` of Module `Mage_Shipping` which  define at   `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/etc/config.xml`

```
<global>
....
<models>
<shipping> <!-- model prefix identifire --->
<class>Mage_Shipping_Model</class>
</shipping>
</models>
..
```